# nightmare with relative imports, how does pep 366 work?

Tags: python, python-import, runpy

I have a "canonical file structure" like that (I'm giving sensible names to ease the reading):

```
mainpack/

  __main__.py
  __init__.py 

  - helpers/
     __init__.py
     path.py

  - network/
     __init__.py
     clientlib.py
     server.py

  - gui/
     __init__.py
     mainwindow.py
     controllers.py
```

In this structure, for example modules contained in each package may want to access the `helpers` utilities through relative imports in something like:

```
# network/clientlib.py
from ..helpers.path import create_dir
```

The program is runned "as a script" using the `__main__.py` file  in this way:

```
python mainpack/
```

Trying to follow the [PEP 366](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/) I've put in `__main__.py` these lines:

```
___package___ = "mainpack"
from .network.clientlib import helloclient
```

But when running:

```
$ python mainpack 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/runpy.py", line 122, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/runpy.py", line 34, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "path/mainpack/__main__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .network.clientlib import helloclient
SystemError: Parent module 'mainpack' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

What's wrong? What is the correct way to handle and effectively use relative imports?

I've tried also to add the current directory to the PYTHONPATH, nothing changes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The loading code seems to be something like [this](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/ihooks.py):

```
    try:
        return sys.modules[pkgname]
    except KeyError:
        if level < 1:
            warn("Parent module '%s' not found while handling "
                 "absolute import" % pkgname, RuntimeWarning, 1)
            return None
        else:
            raise SystemError, ("Parent module '%s' not loaded, cannot "
                                "perform relative import" % pkgname)
```

which makes me think that maybe your module is not on sys.path. If you start Python (normally) and just type "import mainpack" on the prompt, what does it do? It *should* be able to find it.

I have tried it myself and got the same error. After reading a bit I found the following solution:

```
# foo/__main__.py
import sys
mod = __import__('foo')
sys.modules["foo"]=mod

__package__='foo'
from .bar import hello

hello()
```

It seems a bit hackish to me but it does work. The trick seems to be making sure package `foo` is loaded so the import can be relative.

Comment: I'm able to import it from the directory I'm launching, I've to watch this better

Comment: @pygabriel Is it possible for you to zip it and put it on the web somewhere?

Comment: @pygabriel Found a solution. It may not be very beautiful but it does work :)

Comment: thank you very very much, anyway this saves a lot of hackish code in other modules! (various sys.path munging)

Answer (score 46):

The "boilerplate" given in [PEP 366](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/) seems incomplete.  Although it sets the `__package__` variable, it doesn't actually import the package, which is also needed to allow relative imports to work.  *extraneon*'s solution is on the right track.

Note that it is not enough to simply have the directory containing the module in `sys.path`, the corresponding package needs to be explicitly imported. The following seems like a better boilerplate than what was given in [PEP 366](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/) for ensuring that a python module can be executed regardless of how it is invoked (through a regular `import`, or with `python -m`, or with `python`, from any location):

```
# boilerplate to allow running as script directly
if __name__ == "__main__" and __package__ is None:
    import sys, os
    # The following assumes the script is in the top level of the package
    # directory.  We use dirname() to help get the parent directory to add to
    # sys.path, so that we can import the current package.  This is necessary 
    # since when invoked directly, the 'current' package is not automatically
    # imported.
    parent_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    sys.path.insert(1, parent_dir)
    import mypackage
    __package__ = str("mypackage")
    del sys, os

# now you can use relative imports here that will work regardless of how this
# python file was accessed (either through 'import', through 'python -m', or 
# directly.
```

If the script is not at the top level of the package directory and you need to import a module below the top level, then the `os.path.dirname` has to be repeated until the `parent_dir` is the directory containing the top level.

Comment: This was hard to find, but exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly! On a side note: It's recommended to use sys.path.insert(1, parent_dir) (instead of 0) if not sys.path.append(), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095037/why-use-sys-path-appendpath-instead-of-sys-path-insert1-path

Comment: Could you show us the file structure? Also, why `str("mypackage")` instead of just `"mypackage"`?

Comment: The `str()` is there in case `unicode_literals` was imported from `__future__`, since python2 doesn't like `unicode` strings for the package name. In all other cases the `str()` has no effect and can be safely removed.

Answer (score 7):

Inspired by extraneon's and taherh's answers here is some code that runs up the file tree until it runs out of `__init__.py` files to build the full package name.  This is definitely hacky, but does seem to work regardless of the depth of the file in your directory tree.  It seems absolute imports are **heavily** encouraged.

```
import os, sys
if __name__ == "__main__" and __package__ is None:
    d,f = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    f = os.path.splitext(f)[0]
    __package__ = [f] #__package__ will be a reversed list of package name parts
    while os.path.exists(os.path.join(d,'__init__.py')): #go up until we run out of __init__.py files
        d,name = os.path.split(d) #pull of a lowest level directory name 
        __package__.append(name)  #add it to the package parts list
    __package__ = ".".join(reversed(__package__)) #create the full package name
    mod = __import__(__package__) #this assumes the top level package is in your $PYTHONPATH
    sys.modules[__package__] = mod  #add to modules
```

Comment: This worked for me, except that i change the first \_\_package\_\_ = [f] to \_\_package\_\_ = [].  It seems that relative pathing doesn't work correctly if the package name is set to the module loading it -- rather, it must be the package containing that module.

Comment: I've been looking for a solution for this problem for a long time and it works (with the patch of @KDN). I use Python 2.7 with `from __future__ import absolute_import`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a minimal setup based on most of the other answers, tested on python 2.7 with a package layout like so. It also has the advantage that you can call the `runme.py` script from anywhere and it *seems* like it's doing the right thing - I haven't yet tested it in a more complex setup, so caveat emptor...  etc.

This is basically Brad's answer above with the insert into sys.path others have described.

```
packagetest/
  __init__.py       # Empty
  mylib/
    __init__.py     # Empty
    utils.py        # def times2(x): return x*2
  scripts/
    __init__.py     # Empty
    runme.py        # See below (executable)
```

`runme.py` looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
if __name__ == '__main__' and __package__ is None:
    from os import sys, path
    d = path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))
    __package__ = []
    while path.exists(path.join(d, '__init__.py')):
        d, name = path.split(d)
        __package__.append(name)
    __package__ = ".".join(reversed(__package__))
    sys.path.insert(1, d)
    mod = __import__(__package__)
    sys.modules[__package__] = mod

from ..mylib.utils import times2

print times2(4)
```