# Organizing multiple Python applications and shared library packages

Tags: python, package

Suppose that I am writing two applications for my employer, we'll call them **App1** and **App2**. These applications depend on some packages containing code needed by both. Let's say that **App1** depends on **PackageA** and **PackageB**. **App2** depends on **PackageB** and **PackageC**. The organizing strategy that seems natural to me would be to check everything into version control like this:

```
repo_root
+--- App1
|    +--- App1.py
|    +--- ... and so on
+--- App2
|    +--- ... files for App2
+--- PackageA
|    +--- __init__.py
|    +--- ... and more files
+--- PackageB
|    +--- ... files for PackageB
+--- PackageC
     +--- ... files for PackageC
```

The problem comes with importing the packages. For example, **App1** and **App2** both need to import **PackageB**, but I can't just put "import PackageB" into the main file for each of these applications. Python doesn't search the parent directory for packages to import.

I know a couple of options to do this, but they both seem a little ugly. One strategy that I've used before is to put the main file for **App1** and **App2** into the "repo_root" directory. Then the two main files can import the packages without any problems. Another option is to use sys.path.append and **file** to figure out what the parent directory is and add it to the path that Python searches for modules.

Is there a clean, elegant way to do something like this? Thanks for your help.

**Update:** While the virtualenv solution can help a great deal when it comes to dealing with packages and dependencies, it almost seems like overkill for a problem that could be solved by a relative import. Carrying out a relative import seems to be fiendishly complicated, however. There is [PEP 366](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943847/nightmare-with-relative-imports-how-does-pep-366-work), but that is quite complicated and probably wouldn't allow importing outside of a package anyway. I spent some time looking at [importlib](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/importlib/1.0.1), but I'm pretty sure that doesn't allow importing outside of a package either. Many people seem to use munging of the sys.path, of which [this](http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Python/comp.lang.python/2009-03/msg03072.html) seems to be the best example that I've found. But, as I mentioned, this seems a rather hackish way to do things. I've spent nearly all day on investigating this, and I don't think that there is an answer. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I now believe there is no clean, non-hackish way to do a relative import without bringing in a heavy-hitter like virtualenv and some .pth files. Anyway, thanks again for your help. I'll mark this as answered since virtualenv is the only option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution you can use for this is to have a [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) for each of your apps, and then use a relative [.pth](http://bob.pythonmac.org/archives/2005/02/06/using-pth-files-for-python-development/) file to point to the Packages. This gives you fine control over the environment each of the apps is being developed in and avoids the "but I've got package_x on my machine!" problems in testing.

Comment: I've been reading and watching some screencasts, and I think I'm getting the idea. I can create a virtualenv bootstrap script for App1 and App2 that would install the needed open source libraries as well as the '.pth' file (which has to be placed in a 'site-packages' sort of folder). After checkout, runnning the bootstrap would create the environment that allows the app to run. For deployment, I could use the same bootstrap to set up the production server? Is this about correct?

Comment: Pretty much. The big bonus of developing in a virtualenv is knowing exactly what the deployment requirements are, and deploying in a virtualenv is definetely an option to be considered.

Answer (score 1):

[virtualenv](http://iamzed.com/2009/05/07/a-primer-on-virtualenv/) is a clean and elegant way to deal with such issues.  Read the primer, then the summary on [pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv), then install it and give it a try!