# Why use sys.path.append(path) instead of sys.path.insert(1, path)?

Tags: python, path, python-import, pythonpath

**Edit:** based on a Ulf Rompe's comment, **it is important you use "1" instead of "0"**, otherwise you will break [sys.path](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path).

I have been doing python for quite a while now (over a year), and I am always confused as to why people recommend you use `sys.path.append()` instead of `sys.path.insert()`.  Let me demonstrate.

Let's say I am working on a module named PyWorkbooks (that is installed on my computer), but I am simultaneously working on a different module (let's say PyJob) that incorporates PyWorkbooks.  As I'm working on PyJob I find errors in PyWorkbooks that I am correcting, so I would like to import a development version.

There are multiple ways to work on both (I could put my PyWorkbooks project inside of PyJob, for instance), but sometimes I will still need to play with the path.  However, **I cannot simply do a `sys.path.append()` to the folder where PyWorkbooks is at**.  Why?  Because python will find my installed PyWorkbooks first!

This is why you have to do a sys.path.insert(1, path_to_dev_pyworkbooks)

In summary:

```
sys.path.append(path_to_dev_pyworkbooks)
import PyWorkbooks # does NOT import dev pyworkbooks, imports installed one
```

or:

```
sys.path.insert(1, path_to_dev_pyworkbooks) # based on comments you should use **1 not 0**
import PyWorkbooks # imports correct file
```

This has caused a few hangups for me in the past, and I would really like it if we (as a community) started recommending `sys.path.insert(1, path)`, as if you are manually inserting a path I think it is safe to say that that is the path you want to use!

Or do I have something wrong?  It's a question that sometimes bothers me and I wanted it in the open!

Comment: I've done `sys.path.insert(1, dev_folder)` but it's still not finding the dev module, and only using the installed module.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you have multiple versions of a package / module, you need to be using [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html) (emphasis mine):

> `virtualenv` is a tool to create isolated Python environments.
>
> The basic problem being addressed is one of dependencies and versions, and indirectly permissions. **Imagine you have an application that needs version 1 of LibFoo, but another application requires version 2. How can you use both these applications?** If you install everything into `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages` (or whatever your platform’s standard location is), it’s easy to end up in a situation where you unintentionally upgrade an application that shouldn’t be upgraded.
>
> Or more generally, what if you want to install an application and *leave it be*? If an application works, any change in its libraries or the versions of those libraries can break the application.
>
> Also, what if you can’t install packages into the global `site-packages` directory? For instance, on a shared host.
>
> In all these cases, `virtualenv` can help you. It creates an environment that has its own installation directories, that doesn’t share libraries with other virtualenv environments (and optionally doesn’t access the globally installed libraries either).

That's why people consider `insert(0,`  to be wrong -- it's an incomplete, stopgap solution to the problem of managing multiple environments.

Comment: Thanks, I vaguely knew something like this existed but I haven't actually checked it out till now.

So what I would have to do with this is run everything from the interpreter in the virtual environment... that could work as well.  Thanks!

Comment: This is a suggestion but does not directly answer the question (e.g. I have strong reasons not to use `virtualenv` and actually am looking for the associated answer to the OP)

Comment: @javadba That may be true for your case, but most people asking this question should be using `venv`.

Answer (score 54):

If you really need to use sys.path.insert, consider leaving sys.path[0] as it is:

```
sys.path.insert(1, path_to_dev_pyworkbooks)
```

This could be important since 3rd party code may rely on [sys.path documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path%20documentation) conformance:

> As initialized upon program startup, the first item of this list,
>   path[0], is the directory containing the script that was used to
>   invoke the Python interpreter.

Answer (score 13):

you are confusing the concept of appending and prepending. the following code is prepending:

```
sys.path.insert(1,'/thePathToYourFolder/')
```

it places the new information at the beginning (well, second, to be precise) of the search sequence that your interpreter will go through. `sys.path.append()` puts things at the very end of the search sequence.

it is advisable that you use something like `virtualenv` instead of manually coding your package directories into the `PYTHONPATH` everytime. for setting up various ecosystems that separate your site-packages and possible versions of python, read these two blogs:

1. [python ecosystems introduction](http://mirnazim.org/writings/python-ecosystem-introduction/)
2. [bootstrapping python virtual environments](http://ncoghlan_devs-python-notes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/venv_bootstrap.html)

if you do decide to move down the path to environment isolation you would certainly benefit by looking into virtualenvwrapper: http://www.doughellmann.com/docs/virtualenvwrapper/

Comment: The links "python ecosystems introduction", "bootstrapping python virtual environments" have retired, please consider revitalising them.