# adding directory to sys.path /PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, mechanize, python-import, pythonpath

I am trying to import a module from a particular directory.

The problem is that if I use `sys.path.append(mod_directory)` to append the path and then open the python interpreter, the directory `mod_directory` gets added to the end of the list sys.path. If I export the `PYTHONPATH` variable before opening the python interpreter, the  directory gets added to the start of the list. In the latter case I can import the module but in the former, I cannot.

Can somebody explain why this is happening and give me a solution to add the `mod_directory` to the start, *inside* a python script ?

Comment: I have tried [`site` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#site.addsitedir).

Answer (score 286, accepted):

This is working as documented.  Any paths specified in `PYTHONPATH` are documented as normally coming after the working directory but before the standard interpreter-supplied paths.  `sys.path.append()` appends to the existing path.  See [here](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) and [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path).  If you want a particular directory to come first, simply insert it at the head of sys.path:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/path/to/mod_directory')
```

That said, there are usually better ways to manage imports than either using `PYTHONPATH` or manipulating `sys.path` directly.  See, for example, the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893598/pythonpath-vs-sys-path).

Comment: thanks for the reply. The problem was that I didn't realize that to add module packaged as a .egg file you have to include the filename instead of just the directory in python 2.6

Comment: Hey man, this broke my django.  Are you sure you mean to tell people to put it at the top?!?!!?

Comment: @RClaven, sorry, it's hard to tell what action and results you are referring to: "put it at the top" and "broke my django" aren't very precise.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: For more about how sys.path works, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38403654/850326

Comment: just a side note: `sys.path` is zero-indexed as any list, so it should be `sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/mod_directory')`

Comment: @V.K.Thanks for noticing that after all this time! Fixed.

Comment: You really should use "1" instead of "0"! Otherwise you break [sys.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path). See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/10095037/125507.

Comment: Please read the end of the answer: this change to sys.path is only for the running Python program.

Answer (score 18):

You could use:

```
import os
path = 'the path you want'
os.environ['PATH'] += ':'+path
```

Comment: you need ';' in windows.

Answer (score 12):

As to me, i need to caffe to my python path. I can add it's path to the file 
 `/home/xy/.bashrc` by add

`export PYTHONPATH=/home/xy/caffe-master/python:$PYTHONPATH`.

to my `/home/xy/.bashrc` file.

But when I use pycharm, the path is still not in.

So I can add path to `PYTHONPATH` variable, by run -> edit Configuration.

[image]

Comment: The simplest is the best answer, add this for development will make the autocomplete work

Comment: I have updated the .bashrc as explained above but did not reflect in the jupyter notebook. Jupyter notebook still says module not found.

Answer (score 2):

When running a Python script from Powershell under Windows, this should work:

```
$pathToSourceRoot = "C:/Users/Steve/YourCode"
$env:PYTHONPATH = "$($pathToSourceRoot);$($pathToSourceRoot)/subdirs_if_required"

# Now run the actual script
python your_script.py
```

Answer (score 1):

Temporarily changing dirs works well for importing:

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(<module_path>)
import <module>
os.chdir(cwd)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work; fails here on Python 3.8.11 with `No module named '<module>'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

is a general approach to add folder where the script is placed into syspath. Helps with Python 3 if you are running script from different places but still want imports to work.