# Using PyInstaller to make Kivy App excuteable

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, pyinstaller

After creating a spec (with pyinstaller) file and adding the needed code lines (as kivy documentation describes) i get this txt file "warnHR_specialist" with tons of "missing module named........." lines.

Furthermore GUI it self is working but when im trying to use a button linked to a function i got a Fatal Error saying "Failed to execute script".

This button catches a txt file path, open it & manipulte data using pandas module..is it possible that i should add os module? im really comfused...

**Here is the modules im using in my app:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import re
import pandas as pd
```

**I used this command to create the spec file :**

```
 pyinstaller --onedir --name=HR_specialist --windowed "my_file_path_here\HR_specialist.py"
```

**Here is the spec file i got + the kivy changes i made inside it as they describe:**

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
from kivy.deps import sdl2, glew
from os import path
block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['C:\\Users\\kedem_000\\PycharmProjects\\Projects\\HR_specialist\\HR_specialist.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\kedem_000\\PycharmProjects\\Projects\\HRexe'],
             binaries=None,
             datas=None,
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='HR_specialist',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=False )

coll = COLLECT(exe, Tree('C:\Users\kedem_000\PycharmProjects\Projects\HR_specialist'),
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='HR_specialist')
```

Im trying to solve this problem for more then two weeks and im losing my mind...

If any more information is needed please comment.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> Furthermore GUI it self is working but when im trying to use a button linked to a function i got a Fatal Error saying "Failed to execute script".

If GUI works, it means dependencies were successfully packaged into exe/folder (in your case folder). Judgind from this quote even `Button` event works, so Kivy should be packaged correctly.

However, the errors are about some missing modules (please include log!), therefore it means *those* modules weren't packaged, or Python can't import it. If they weren't packaged, you'll probably need to include them in `hidden_imports` if `pyinstaller` forgot to fetch them to folder too.

If they were packaged (open folder, check), they probably can't be imported. This would seem like you manipulated a path from which imports are fetched in Pycharm and you'll need to [edit it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16114586/5994041).