# CUDA 9.0 and pycuda, error:CompileError: nvcc compilation ... kernel.cu failed

Tags: python, visual-studio, pycuda

```
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import numpy
a = numpy.random.randn(4,4)
a = a.astype(numpy.float32)
a_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(a.nbytes)
cuda.memcpy_htod(a_gpu, a)
mod = SourceModule("""
__global__ void doublify(float *a)
{
int idx = threadIdx.x + threadIdx.y*4;
a[idx] *= 2;
}
""")
```

I just installed CUDA 9.0 and pycuda, and I am following the tutorial to run the first cuda program.
But it always turns out error:

CompileError: nvcc compilation of c:\users\rl74173\appdata\local\temp\tmp6nww2c\kernel.cu failed

I did some research and find some answers to this before. So I add this before running:

```
import os
os.system("vcvarsamd64.bat")
```

But it is still error.

I also see someone figure it out by adding line below to nvcc.profile

```
COMPILER-BINDIR = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\amd64
```

I installed visual studio community 2017,so in my case, I tried

```
COMPILER-BINDIR = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc\lib\amd64
```

But it doesn't help.

Comment: Did you ever fix this? Where is `nvcc.profiles` located? edit: by the way, shouldn't this have been "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\Hostx64\amd64" or more recently "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\bin\Hostx64\x64"

Comment: I have tried a lot of different ways in different machines, but never succeed yet. I cannot figure out why, cuda just doesn't work with me.

Comment: I've managed to get CUDA v9.1.xxx to work with Visal Studio 2017 by installing an older version (V15.4). I can create a DLL now, which I can probably source from Python. However, I would prefer using PyCuda. Still having this error though.

Comment: Ok, I've added a `print(cmdline)` in PyCuda's compiler.py. I've run the *exact* command in a windows cmd window (with vcvars64 run): `nvcc --cubin -arch sm_50 -m64 -Ic:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pycuda\cuda kernel.cu`... and it works! Why doesn't pycuda work then....

Comment: better idea: I've added `print(stdout)` after the call. Output: `"nvcc fatal   : Cannot find compiler 'cl.exe' in PATH"`. So it seems the call to `vcvars[...].bat` does not change the PATH correctly.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I fixed it for me. The problem is that running `vcvars64.bat` sets the path environment in a **sub**shell... and then closes it, so the set path disappears again.

What you want, is to change the path yourself: add the path to the `cl.exe` compiler file. For that, I referenced [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45522081/6717178). In my case, I had to add this at the start to my .py file:

```
import os
if (os.system("cl.exe")):
    os.environ['PATH'] += ';'+r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\bin\HostX64\x64"
if (os.system("cl.exe")):
    raise RuntimeError("cl.exe still not found, path probably incorrect")
```

I hope this works for you.

Edit: you need to run a MSVS version compatible with CUDA. I.e. CUDA v9.0 doesn't support MSVS2017 and CUDA v9.1 only supports version 15.4, not later versions. Try if it works by running `nvcc.exe` from the Native Tools Command Prompt for Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks! I'd like to have a try.

Comment: I tried with old versions but failed again. So I just move on to Visual Studio 2017 and CUDA 9.0, but I am confused now. After I installed these two, do I still need to add certain path to the system environment? Or do I still need to add any lines into CUDA files? 

BTW: I installed the pycuda from the PyCUDA prebuilt binary from Christoph Golke. In Anaconda prompt tpye:
pip install <directory>\pycuda‑2017.1.1+cuda9185‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl

Comment: CompileError: nvcc compilation of C:\Users\rl74173\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpy396ip6k\kernel.cu failed

Comment: @billinair: you should probably edit the `compiler.py`, to see the actual error nvcc is throwing.

Comment: @billinair looked it up. Vs2017 is only supported form Cuda 9.1. And even then, you should install vs v15.4, not the latest version.

Comment: @billinair Also, `cuda9185` in the PyCuda package you used refers to Cuda v9.1.85. So if you installed CUDA v9.0 it will not be compatible with that PyCuda package.

Comment: I cannot locate the right compiler.py, because no pycuda in the folder  C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pkgs

Comment: that's because it is probably in `C:\Users******\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pycuda`. In the file, around line 120, you have the line `result, stdout, stderr = call_capture_output(cmdline, cwd=file_dir, error_on_nonzero=False)`. Below that you can add print(result); print(stdout); print(stderr), etc.

Comment: I add some lines and get this.    
`b"nvcc fatal   : Value 'sm_21' is not defined for option 'gpu-architecture'\r\n"`
As I search online, it seems that my GPU is out of date or the driver is too new for the GPU. Not very sure.

Comment: Yep, too old and have been removed. Can't help you there.