# How do I reference a python file nested within a nested package in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, module, package

Trying to understand how to properly use another module when its nested within a folder. I tried implementing a package using the `__init__.py` as documented in the [Packages section](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) of Modules. I am not finding much success. Here is the file structure.

[image: File Structure]

For example, I want to be able to reference a class contained within `credentials.py` in `propeller.py`. Another use case, I want to reference a function from within `base.py` in `propeller.py`. Looking forward to hearing how other approach this. Thanks!

Comment: Fundamentally, you need to be able to find the file you are looking for from the PATH variable. Usually, "installing" a module involves adding the root directory of your library to the PATH. In a *nix system, something like: https://askubuntu.com/questions/250929/pythonpath-environment-variable

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Is the main module 'the_machine' in your [Module Search Path](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)?  If so, you should be able to `import the_machine.credentials`. Otherwise, either [add it to your sys.path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114391/adding-directory-to-sys-path-pythonpath) or  [import it directly using the path.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path).