# how to import a class in python from another class?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a folder defined "models". inside that, I have a python class(site.py)

I want to import that class to my main class.

I tried several ways but not working.

**site.py**

```
class site(object):
....
```

**Main.py**

```
def BuildATGSiteConfig():    
    a= site()
    return a
```

Comment: Have you create a file name as `__init__.py` on the same directory?

Comment: Do you have the line 'from site import site'?

Comment: `site.py` is a bad name for a file, because there's a [python initialization thingy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html) that's already using that name.

Comment: [Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114391/adding-directory-to-sys-path-pythonpath)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `__init__.py` [this way you declare that the directory is a package] file in directory, models. After that, in your main.py file, 
write `from site import *`, this will import every functions into `main`'s scope. However, you can choose to publish/get only required functions form `site`. In such case. use `from site import <function_name>`. So, your `main.py` should look like

```
from site import *
from_site = site() #getting into local namespace.
from_site.site() #this is a function in site, and calling it in main.
```