# Getting module not found error when i try to run my python test scripts through cmd

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, automated-tests

when i run my code with pycharm my code is getting executed but same thing if i try to do with the help of cmd i am getting the below error . 
I am not sure why i am getting this error can any one please help me out .
The python version which i am using is 3.6.4

```
from unittest import TestLoader, TestSuite, TextTestRunner
from Test.TestSuite import HTMLTestRunner
from Test.Scripts.login_page import LoginPage
from Test.Scripts.register_page import Register
from Test.Scripts.category_page import CategoryPage
from Test.Scripts.Footer_page import Footer
from Test.Scripts.hamburger_page import HamburgerPage
from Test.Scripts.header_page import Header
from Test.Scripts.message_page import MessagePage
from Test.Scripts.new_topic_page import NewTopicPage
from Test.Scripts.profile_preference_page import ProfilePreferencePage
from Test.Scripts.search_page import SearchPage
from Test.Scripts.topic_page import TopicPage
from Test.Scripts.user_profile_links_page import UserProfilePage


if __name__ == "__main__":

 loader = TestLoader()

 suite = TestSuite((

    loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(LoginPage),
    loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(Register),
    loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(CategoryPage),
    loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(Footer),
    loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(HamburgerPage),
    loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(Header),
    loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(MessagePage),
    loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(NewTopicPage),
    loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(ProfilePreferencePage),
    loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(SearchPage),
    loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(TopicPage),
    loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(UserProfilePage)

    ))
#run test sequentially using simple TextTestRunner
runner = TextTestRunner(verbosity=1)
#runner.run(suite)

# open the report file
outfile = open("forum_page_test_results.html", "w")

# configure HTMLTestRunner options
runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(stream=outfile, title='Test report', description='Acceptance Tests')

# run the suite using HTMLTestRunner
runner.run(suite)
```

error :  File "TestRunner.py", line 2, in 
    from Test.TestSuite import HTMLTestRunner
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Test'

Comment: Show the exact command you're using to run the script

Comment: This is the command i am using /test_forum_page/Test/TestSuite$ python TestRunner.py

Answer (score 0):

If the module that you are developing is named Test, you might need to add the directory containing this module to sys.path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/mod_directory')
```

See:
[adding directory to sys.path /PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114391/adding-directory-to-sys-path-pythonpath)