# How to use non-installable modules from DAG code?

Tags: python-3.x, git, airflow, python-module

I have a Git repository which (among other things) holds Airflow DAGs in `airflow` directory. I have a clone of the repository besides an install directory of Airflow. `airflow` directory in Git is pointed to by `AIRFLOW_HOME` configuration variable.

I would like to allow imports from modules in the repository that are listed *outside* `airflow` folder (please see the structure below).

```
<repo root>
   |_airflow
      |_dags
         |_dag.py
   |_module1
   |_module2
   |_...
```

So that in `dag.py` I can do:

```
from module1 import Module1
```

Currently, it does not seem possible without [tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114391/adding-directory-to-sys-path-pythonpath) like editing `sys.path` explicitly which is not very elegant and has to be done in each of the dag source files...

Making an installable package out of the `module1` is also out of the question.

Comment: Why can't you make them into a package? Is it code privacy issue? If so, to what degree does it need to be kept private?

Comment: @PirateNinjas: You guessed right - one of the issues is the code privacy.

Comment: I'm aware of just 2 ways (both of which, I assume, your'e already aware): **[1]** package your code into an [Airflow plugin](https://airflow.apache.org/plugins.html) **[2]** Made code discoverable by updating python path; but apart from updating `sys.path` programmatically, we can also (I personally do) update `PYTHONPATH` once and for all in `.bashrc`

Comment: An alternative, to juggling the path would be to obfuscate the code so you can deploy it a package or directly as code. You could do this by using cython to build your package into shared object files. This isn't a perfect solution, but it will work for your problem I think.

Comment: @y2k-shubham: Indeed, maybe Airflow plugins are the way to go. One base class that does the path manipulation could serve the purpose of setting the environment for all of the inheriting DAGs I create. Please convert the comment to an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Re-writing conclusion from discussions here*

---

Broadly, there are 2 possible ways

1. Package your code into an [Airflow plugin](https://airflow.apache.org/plugins.html)
2. Make your code discoverable to dag-definition-file(s) parsing processes by updating `PYTHONPATH`. Here again we have following options

   (a) Update `PYTHONPATH` on system level [using `bashrc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53876478/3679900) / equivalent (once-and-for-all) or just [`export` the updated `PYTHONPATH`](https://askubuntu.com/a/250935/590275) for current bash session

   (b) Programmatically [update `sys.path`](https://askubuntu.com/q/470982/590275) in the beginning of DAG-definition file