# Importing python modules and packages

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I have following project structure,

```
|
├── database
│   ├── db_adapter.py
│   ├── db_layer
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── mysql_adapter.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── scripts
│       └── schema.sql
|
└── workflow
    ├── dags
    │   ├── dss_controller.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    |
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── plugins
```

I want to import db_adapter.py module inside dss_controller module, when I tried do it following error shown,

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'database'
```

How can I do the correct importing of the modules?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57693865/3679900)

Comment: @y2k-shubham, yes it's working. Any particular reasons for not working the import using init files here (in airflow dag files)?