# DAG does not recognize tasks Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I have a file that defines the DAG object:

**dags/my_dag.py**

```
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime

default_args = {
    'owner': 'pilota',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 10, 1),
    'email': ['some@email.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0,
}

bts_dag = DAG(
    'hist_data_etl', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='@once')
```

Then in another file, I import the created dag and define my tasks:

```
from ingestion.airflow_home.dags.my_dag import bts_dag
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from ingestion.datatransformer import fetch_and_transform_bts_data_col

NUM_ENGINES = 4

template_command = '''
    ipcluster start n {{ params.cluster }}
    sleep 5
'''

start_iparallel_cluster = BashOperator(
    task_id='start_cluster',
    bash_command=template_command,
    retries=3,
    params={'params': NUM_ENGINES},
    dag=bts_dag)


import_hist_bts_data_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='fetch_transform_hist_col',
    python_callable=fetch_and_transform_bts_data_col,
    op_kwargs={
        'bucket': 'some-bucket', 'path': 'hello/', 'num_files': 1
    },
    dag=bts_dag)

start_iparallel_cluster >> import_hist_bts_data_task
```

sanity check:

`$ airflow list_dags`

yields:

```
 -------------------------------------------------------------------
DAGS
-------------------------------------------------------------------
hist_data_etl
```

**however**

`$ airflow list_tasks hist_data_etl`

doesn't output any of my tasks. Somehow airflow isn't registering the tasks to belong to the DAG I defined in another file.

Please help :)

Comment: did you try putting both *`DAG` object creation* and *`task`-creation* (`operator`(s) instantiation) in a single file?

Comment: I did. And that works fine.I want to be able to build and execute these operators in another file in a parent folder

Comment: The reason why is that the function I defined and that are being used by the PythonOperator are located in another directory. I tried importing them into days/my_dag.py but I’m having import issues because those function are in another parent folder

Comment: For resolving import errors in Airflow, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57693865/3679900)

Comment: that's helpful, thank you. What about the other way around -> importing the defined dag into another module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Because of the way [dag-file parsing](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/utils/dag_processing.py#L290) works in Airflow, I don't expect this to work
- Even I don't have complete idea of internals, but Airflow spawns [child processes to parse dag-definition files](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-160) (files identified by some traits). Each process parses a different subset of files => it is likely that different files are processed by different processes
- I believe that in your implementation, the logical order of parsing the files (parse dag file first and then task file) is not preserved and therefore things don't work

---

However with some modification in your approach, you can get this working

first file

```
# dag_object_creator.py

from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime

default_args = {
    'owner': 'pilota',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 10, 1),
    'email': ['some@email.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0,
}

def create_dag_object():
    bts_dag = DAG(dag_id='hist_data_etl',
                  default_args=default_args,
                  schedule_interval='@once')
    return bts_dag
```

second file

```
# tasks_creator.py

# this import statement is problematic
# from ingestion.airflow_home.dags.my_dag import bts_dag
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from ingestion.datatransformer import fetch_and_transform_bts_data_col

NUM_ENGINES = 4

template_command = '''
    ipcluster start n {{ params.cluster }}
    sleep 5
'''

def create_bash_task(bts_dag):
    start_iparallel_cluster = BashOperator(
        task_id='start_cluster',
        bash_command=template_command,
        retries=3,
        params={'params': NUM_ENGINES},
        dag=bts_dag)
    return start_iparallel_cluster


def create_python_task(bts_dag):
    import_hist_bts_data_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id='fetch_transform_hist_col',
        python_callable=fetch_and_transform_bts_data_col,
        op_kwargs={
            'bucket': 'pilota-ml-raw-store', 'path': 'flights/', 'num_files': 1
        },
        dag=bts_dag)
    return import_hist_bts_data_task
```

third file

```
# dag_definition_file.py

import dag_object_creator
import tasks_creator

# create dag object
# stuff from 'dag_object_creator.py' can be put here directly,
# i just broke down things for clarity
bts_dag = dag_object_creator.create_dag_object()

# create tasks
start_iparallel_cluster = tasks_creator.create_bash_task(bts_dag)
import_hist_bts_data_task = tasks_creator.create_python_task(bts_dag)

# chaining tasks
start_iparallel_cluster >> import_hist_bts_data_task
```

---

above layout of code would enforce following behaviour

- upfront process starts parsing only `dag_definition_file.py` (other two files are skipped because no "DAG"s are created at global scope)
- as and when `import` statements are executed, these files are parsed
- when dag / task creation statements are executed, DAG & task objects respectively get created in global scope

therefore everything comes into place nicely and this implementation *should work* (not tested, but based on anecdotal knowledge)

---

Suggested reads

- [`dag_processing.py`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/utils/dag_processing.py#L290)
- [`default_airflow.cfg`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg#L504)
- [Airflow Scheduler Basics](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/Scheduler+Basics)
- [AIP-24 DAG Persistence in DB using JSON](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/AIP-24+DAG+Persistence+in+DB+using+JSON+for+Airflow+Webserver+and+%28optional%29+Scheduler?focusedCommentId=123898950)

Comment: I moved the definition of task and dag into the `mydag.py` file but I'm getting import issues when trying to import a file from another parent directory.