# Python importing from incorrect module (which bears the same name), VSC

Tags: import, visual-studio-code, python-3.7

I have two modules, both named `connection.py` in two separate environments listed below. Both of the folders containing `connection.py` are in my PYTHONPATH system environment variable.

However, if that of `spec` is not placed above that of `bvbot`, spec's `test_connection.py` attempts to import from the `connection.py` of bvbot.

If in cmd, I can resolve this by moving the path of spec above that of bvbot. But, in Visual Studio Code, spec's `test_connection.py` still imports from bvbot's `connection.py`.

The two environments of interest are:

```
C:\Users\You_A\Desktop\2016Coding\VirtualEnviroments\spec\spec_trading
C:\Users\You_A\Desktop\2016Coding\VirtualEnviroments\bvbot\Legacy_bvbot
```

Structure of the `spec` path above:

```
src/
    spec_trading/
        __init__.py
        connection.py
tests/
    __init__.py
    connection.py
```

spec test_connection.py:

```
import pytest

from connection import Connection, OandaConnection


class TestConnection:
    def test_poll_timeout(self):
        connection = Connection()
        timeout = 10.0
        connection.set_poll_timeout(timeout)
        assert connection.poll_timeout == timeout
```

What I am doing wrong here? How can I resolve this without resorting to manually faffing with my systems environment variables and resolve the VSC issue?

Comment: Take a look at `import sys; print(sys.path)`, the order of this should give you an idea. https://leemendelowitz.github.io/blog/how-does-python-find-packages.html

Comment: @Joe first thing I notice is that C:\Users\You_A\Desktop\2016Coding\VirtualEnviroments\spec\spec_trading\src\spec_trading is missing from sys.path when run via VSC cmd terminal. I'm lost, but I'll read up

Comment: You could try to add it manually to see if this fixes your problems https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114391/adding-directory-to-sys-path-pythonpath

Comment: And if you run it from a "normal" terminal, not the one inside vscode? You are using virtual environments, right?

Comment: @joe normal terminal is fine. Using virtual environments.

Comment: Have you checked the VSC terminal which commands are executed on startup? Have you checked which Python interpreter is assigned to the project / folder?

Comment: C:\Users\You_A\Desktop\2016Coding\VirtualEnviroments\spec\spec_trading\src\spec_trading does not appear in sys.path or PYTHONPATH when run through VSC cmd.It does via regular cmd. I'm not sure what you are referring to re 'commands on startup.

Comment: python interpreter is correct.

Comment: Please check `sys.executable` for both cases, this will tell you the interpreter used.

Comment: At the top of the terminal in VSC there might be some commands showing VSC changing the virtual environments.

Comment: both interpreters used are the same ( each checked with sys.executable). VSC shows correct VE being used

Comment: Hm, strange. I am not sure if you are using the virtual environments in a correct way. Have you understood how they work? Usually there is only one environment active. It might be that this is what VSC is trying to do, it activates the one it thinks you need and puts it in the first place. You could manually override this by tinkering with `sys.path` before importing any modules.

Comment: Another option is to change the level you are importing from up one folder and use something like `from spec_trading import connection as spec_conn; from bvbot import connection as bv_conn`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199558/discussion-between-joe-and-dave).

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution is to not use implicit relative imports (I assume this is Python 2.7). Basically use explicit relative imports and make sure the imports resolve within the package they are contained within instead of Python having to search `sys.path` for the module.

And if you are using Python 2.7, put `from __future__ import absolute_import` at the top of the file.