# To be imported is it necessary for a directory to be in sys.path?

Tags: python, sys, relative-import

I have this package I designed which have the following structure,

```
General/
    __init__.py
    Vector/
        __init__.py
        module_1.py
    module_A.py
```

In `module_A` there is a just a function prints a string.

In `module_1` there is,

```
from ...General import module_A
module_A.function()
```

Then I create a separate python file `First.py` which only has the line `import General.Vector.module_1`.

I put this file in to the parent directory of General and locate cmd to the parent directory and run `python First.py`

Then I get the error `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

But if I change `module_1` to

```
from .. import module_A
module_A.function()
```

Then this works.

I searched for a solution and from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time/14132912#14132912) post, I got a good understanding about relative imports. Then it was pointed out to me that if I add my package to `sys.path` then `python First.py` would work regardless of where the `First.py` is located.

So I tried to add my package to `sys.path` as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114391/adding-directory-to-sys-path-pythonpath) post suggests.

I changed my `First.py` to

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/path/to/General')
import General.Vector.module_1
```

But that didn't work.

***1*** I like to know the reason for this two different behaviours for `module_1`'s changes.

***2*** I like to know how to add my package to `sys.path`.

Comment: If you're importing `General.Vector.module_1` then `General` is the top-level package. If you do `from ...General` then it steps *outside* of that package (which is not possible), just to reenter it. It's like if your `pwd` is `/path/to/foo/bar` and instead of `cd ../baz` you do `cd ../../foo/baz`; the `../foo` part is redundant here. Nevertheless it works because the file system is seen as a whole. However Python only knows the structure of your package and that is limited by `General` (i.e. it doesn't know what exists beyond `General`).

Comment: You can add your package to `sys.path` but you should add `"/path/to"` instead of `"path/to/General"` since it attempts to locate the package `General` *inside* that path.

Comment: @a_guest Actually it worked with the `sys.path`

Comment: @a_guest so we are not allowed step out of the top level package at anytime. is it correct?

Comment: That's what the error says, yes. Packages do not necessarily have to live on the file system, so from the perspective of the Python import machinery there is really nothing beyond the top-level package.

Comment: @a_guest  now I get it thank you very much.

Comment: @napuzba It also helped me thank you!