# How do I modify the sys.path in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I've been having this issue fairly consistently over different virtual environments I've created. This is my most recent instance. I created a Python 3.6 virtual environment for a project that uses OpenCV. I downloaded the relevant modules to my virtual environment, but whenever I try to import them in my code, I get the following error:

```
>>> import cv2 as cv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so: undefined symbol: PyCObject_Type
```

I've looked up this error before, and from my understanding, it has something to do with the directories Python is looking at when it is trying to import my modules. I checked `sys.path` and I got the following:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/home/[username]/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/[username]/ECE432_Proj/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/home/[username]/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

So I'm guessing that the bolded parts are where the error is coming from. When I'm trying to import `cv2`, it finds `cv2.so` in a different folder, and tries to import that instead, with no success.

My question is this: how do I modify the `sys.path` so that Python looks at the correct folders when it is trying to find the right module to import?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [adding directory to sys.path /PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114391/adding-directory-to-sys-path-pythonpath)

Comment: Did you define `PYTHONPATH` in your environment? Right now, your Python 3.6 install is looking for libraries under 2.7-specific directories. It wouldn't do that on its own, which makes me think you used `PYTHONPATH` incorrectly (read: at all; it's a hack that's bites you constantly when you need to support multiple versions of Python). `echo $PYTHONPATH` in your regular shell (not Python); I'll guess you made it something terrible (possibly in your `.bashrc`). You *could* remove the bad entries from `sys.path` (it's a plain `list`, with `list` methods), but it's best not to have those entries.

Comment: You’re using 2.7 packages in a 3.6 environment ...

Comment: If you are running this directly though command line you may want to activate it to avoid adding unneeded values to the PYTHONPATH

Comment: @ShadowRanger, your response put me in the right direction. I did check `PYTHONPATH` in my regular shell, and it was set to the wrong directories. I checked `.bashrc` as well, which I remember changing for a different project, so that explains why `PYTHONPATH` is looking at those directories only. I spent a couple days figuring out how `PYTHONPATH` and `sys.path` work, and I commented out the lines in `.bashrc` for the moment, and have settled for appending the relevant directories to `sys.path`, but I wonder if there is a better way to do that.