# Python imports in vscode

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I'm trying to run a simple project in python but I have always the same problem and it drives me crazy every single time.

My project structure looks like the following:

```
└── myproject
    ├── mypackage
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── a.py
        ├── b.py
```

With vscode I open up the myproject folder. When I click on run in the `a.py` file which looks like

```
# a.py
from mypackage import b
.
.
.
```

I always get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mypackage'`. What is confusing to me is that vscode itself sees it correctly and shows the text colored (means it detects the module correctly).

**Edit:**

I want to use myproject as a package so just `import b` won't help.

The solution I found is actually relatively easy. Just type `python3 -m mypackage.a` into the command line in the top myproject directory. Worked for me.

I know this has nothing to do with vscode but I was just confused why vscode seems to accept the import but the python interpreter didn't.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43728431/relative-imports-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-x)

Comment: Not really. I think I put my answer in the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've probably didn't install `myproject` (or `mypackage`, if it is top level Python package), Python cannot find it on the path. You have two options:

1. Install the package.
2. Use relative import `import b`. However, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time) for implications.

I recommend to avoid approaches like adding `mypackage` path to system path (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16114586/8696161)). Maybe [this documentation/tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) can help you to understand better, what happened and why the import you used is not working.

However, I do not know, how VS Code searches for files in project, so I cannot tell you, why it marks it like this...

Comment: The reason why I do it like this is that myproject is a package. And when I want to use pip install myproject afterward it will give me an error when I say import b. But installing the package is also not really an option because I would need to run pip install myproject every time I modify it.

Comment: Take a look at `-e` option for package installation (see [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-e)). It installs package in editable mode, so all modifications take immediate effect.

Answer (score -1):

according to what you mentioned, both file 'a.py' and 'b.py' are in the same directory and if both files are in the same director, you don't have to actually mention the name of the directory in which they are present.

To import the file 'b.py' in 'a.py', you can just simply type the code shown below to import 'b.py':

> import b

This should work.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But as mentioned in the comment before, I want to use myproject as a package. And then I will get in trouble.