# Import file from subdirectory into file in another subdirectory

Tags: python, python-import, python-packaging

I have a python project a folder structure like this:

```
main_directory
  main.py
  drivers
    __init__.py
    xyz.py
  utils
    __init__.py
    connect.py
```

I want to import `connect.py` into `xyz.py` and here's my code:

```
from utils import connect as dc
```

But I keep getting this error no matter what I do, please help:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

**Update**: People are telling me to set the path or directory, I don't understand why I need to do this only for importing file. This is something that should work automatically.

Comment: Why did you tag `pip`? Is it relevant to your question? You do not mention pip in the question. -- How do you run your code? Which command? And from which working directory?

Answer (score 0):

In your utils folder `__init__.py` should be blank. If this doesn't work, try adding `from __future__ import absolute_import` in your `xyz.py` file.

Answer (score -1):

You could move your utils folder into drivers, making the path to the to-be imported file a subdirectory of your executing file, like:

```
main_directory/drivers/utils/connect.py
```

Alternatively, you could try

```
from ..utils import connect as dc
```

This will move up a directory before import.

Lasty, you could add the directory to Path in your script via

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/path/to/mod_directory')
```

For this method, see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114391/adding-directory-to-sys-path-pythonpath)

Comment: I cannot move the folder, and trying by adding the `.` leads to this error `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Comment: I corrected the import statement.

Answer (score -1):

Check your current directory. It must be main_directory.

```
import os
print("Current working directory is: ", os.getcwd()
```

if not, you can change using

```
os.chdir("path/to/main_directory")
```

also works with relative path

```
os.chdir('..')
```

Answer (score -1):

I was also facing same problem when you use row python script so i use the following code at the beginning of the file

```
import os
import sys

current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
parent_dir = os.path.dirname(current_dir)
sys.path.append(parent_dir)
```

This way it will search the require file at parent directory.

Hope this will work for you also..