# Calling IPython from a virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, ipython

I understand that IPython is not [virtualenv-aware](http://rodesia.org/2012/09/04/making-ipython-virtualenv-aware/) and that the most logical solution to this is to install ipython in each virtualenv seperately using

```
pip install ipython
```

So far so good. One thing I noticed is that if the system-wide copy of IPython is called from within a virtualenv using `$> ipython` before IPython is installed under this virtualenv, subsequent `$> ipython` commands will continue to bring up the system-wide ipython copy.

On the other hand, if ipython is **not** called prior to installing it under a virtualenv `$> ipython` will bring up the newly installed copy.

What is the explanation for this?

It also makes me wonder if this behavior means I should expect some trouble down the way?

Comment: Recent versions of IPython should recognise virtualenvs without needing to be installed separately - you'll see a "trying to work in a virtualenv" message when it starts. The 'sticky' command you see is bash caching the location of the `ipython` executable somewhere ([see this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/how-do-i-clear-bashs-cache-of-paths-to-executables)).

Comment: Thomas, thanks for the link about bash caching, it seems that this is exactly what happens. IPython 1.1.0 shows me an 'Attempting to work in a virtualenv' warning but it does not recognise the virtualenv unless installed within a virtualenv - but that's fine I just wanted to make sure the procedure is unproblematic.

Comment: what version of virtualenv are you using, and how are you activating the env? The command you are missing is `hash -r`, which drops the cache of previously run commands, which is typically executed as part of activating an env. Check for `hash -r` in ENV/bin/activate.

Comment: yes, true! As Thomas pointed out, this was a bash caching issue and running `hash -r` before activating an env resolves the problem. FYI I was working with virtualenv 1.10.1

Answer (score 134, accepted):

`alias ipy="python -c 'import IPython; IPython.terminal.ipapp.launch_new_instance()'"`

This is a great way of always being sure that the ipython instance always belongs to the virtualenv's python version.

This works only on ipython >2.0.

[Source](https://coderwall.com/p/xdox9a)

Comment: BTW, profile name can be passed via kwargs. Thanks for that answer!

Answer (score 54):

The answer given by @SiddharthaRT is good! Following this approach, it is simpler for me just:

```
python -m IPython
```

This will use the module IPython through the python bin, ensuring that it refers to the bin from the virtual env.

Answer (score 25):

1. Activate your virtual environment by using `source ~/.virtualenvs/my_venv/bin/activate` or by running `workon my_venv`
   (Depending on how you've installed the my_venv virtual environment)
2. Install ipython

`pip install ipython`

3. Now run ipython from my_venv.

If it still loads the system's ipython, then run `hash -r` in your shell

This will reset the cache of your shell and ensure you don't run another ipython that was already called in this shell session.

Comment: This worked for me but option `-r` is "forget all remembered locations" from the GNU docs. Not sure what is actually forgotten. Do you know @TheDataGuy?

Comment: After searching for half an hour, the `hash -r` command did it for me, thanks!

Comment: @SanderLam Yes and it works in OSX Ventura too! Seems to be the simplest solution for zsh

Answer (score 10):

You can force IPython to use a virtual environment if available by adding file below to `~/.ipython/profile_default/startups`:

```
import os
import sys

if 'VIRTUAL_ENV' in os.environ:
    py_version = sys.version_info[:2] # formatted as X.Y 
    py_infix = os.path.join('lib', ('python%d.%d' % py_version))
    virtual_site = os.path.join(os.environ.get('VIRTUAL_ENV'), py_infix, 'site-packages')
    dist_site = os.path.join('/usr', py_infix, 'dist-packages')

    # OPTIONAL: exclude debian-based system distributions sites
    sys.path = filter(lambda p: not p.startswith(dist_site), sys.path)

    # add virtualenv site
    sys.path.insert(0, virtual_site)
```

I recommend naming it `00-virtualenv.py` so changes will be made as early as possible.

Note: Make sure ipython is installed in the new virtual environment to get this to work.

Comment: This works great in Python 2 environments, but in version 3 envs I get an ImportError stating theres no module named "IPython". Running ipython3 outside the environment works, do you know what I'm missing here?

Comment: Thanks for this. But I think the "Optional" line breaks with python3 as sys.path becomes a filter object which doesn't respond to list methods, right?

Answer (score 8):

As others mentioned, recent versions of ipython are virtualenv aware, so you can use your virtualenv bin [activate](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/#activate-script) script to run ipython using your virtualenv, e.g.

```
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv) $ ipython
WARNING: Attempting to work in a virtualenv. If you encounter problems, please install IPython inside the virtualenv.
```

Comment: So many downvotes.  If this doesn't work for you, please comment with an error message and output of `ipython --version; cat /etc/issue`

Comment: This will work with IPython's console, but will not work with other things, for example IPython kernel.

Answer (score 4):

I'll chime in years later in hopes someone finds this useful.

This solution solves a few problems:

- You don't need iPython installed in the current virtualenv, only for the global Python that matches your virtualenv's Python version (`3.6 != 3.7`).
- Works for users of `pyenv` where your global Python version might be `3.7` and your local virtualenv Python is `3.6` therefore using the global `ipython` will fail.
- Works outside of virtual environments (though not particularly useful as it always targets `python`).

Throw this in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` or what have you:

```sh
# This is a roundabout way to start ipython from inside a virtualenv without it being installed
# in that virtualenv. The only caveot is that the "global" python must have ipython installed.
# What this function does that's different than simply calling the global ipython is it ensures to
# call the ipython that is installed for the same major.minor python version as in the virtualenv.
# This is most useful if you use pyenv for example as global python3 could be 3.7 and local
# virtualenv python3 is 3.6.
function ipy {
  local PY_BIN
  local IPYTHON
  local PYV
  # This quick way will work if ipython is in the virtualenv
  PY_BIN="$(python -c 'import sys; print(sys.executable)')"
  IPYTHON="$(dirname "$PY_BIN")/ipython"
  if [[ -x "$IPYTHON" ]]; then
    "$IPYTHON"
  else
    # Ask the current python what version it is
    PYV="$(python -c 'import sys; print(".".join(str(i) for i in sys.version_info[:2]))')"
    echo "Looking for iPython for Python $PYV"
    # In a new shell (where pyenv should load if equipped) try to find that version
    PY_BIN="$($SHELL -i -c "python$PYV -c 'import sys; print(sys.executable)'")"
    "$(dirname "$PY_BIN")/ipython"
  fi
}
```

Then `source` or open a new terminal and run `ipy`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to open a notebook, even ipython 5 won't help - ipython will disregard the virtualenv (at least on my machine/setup).
You'll need to use rgtk's script, but please make sure to modify the optional filter part and the sys.path.insert as below:

```
import os
import sys

if 'VIRTUAL_ENV' in os.environ:
    py_version = sys.version_info[:2] # formatted as X.Y 
    py_infix = os.path.join('lib', ('python%d.%d' % py_version))
    virtual_site = os.path.join(os.environ.get('VIRTUAL_ENV'), py_infix, 'site-packages')
    dist_site = os.path.join('/usr', py_infix, 'dist-packages')

    # OPTIONAL: exclude debian-based system distributions sites
    # ADD1: sys.path must be a list
    sys.path = list(filter(lambda p: not p.startswith(dist_site), sys.path))

    # add virtualenv site
    # ADD2: insert(0 is wrong and breaks conformance of sys.path
    sys.path.insert(1, virtual_site)
```

- ADD1: in the original script we get back a filter object, we would break sys.path and insert below would fail
- ADD2: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095037/why-use-sys-path-appendpath-instead-of-sys-path-insert1-path) and [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path)

Answer (score 1):

(Debian/Ubuntu) assuming some version (x) of Python3 is installed, then:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y ipython
$ virtualenv --python=python3.x .venv
$ source .venv/bin/activate
$ pip3 install ipython
$ ipython3
```

will launch ipython running your version of Python3.