# "ImportError: No module named google.protobuf" but it's definitely installed

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, python-3.5

I've installed the `protobuf` package but I'm unable to import it.

```
> pip uninstall protobuf
... uninstalls
> pip install protobuf
... installs. confirm that it's installed:
pip install protobuf
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): protobuf in     ./.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in ./.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from protobuf)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.9 in ./.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from protobuf)
```

Back in `ipython`:

```
In [1]: from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-3baca6afb060> in <module>()
----> 1 from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor

ImportError: No module named google.protobuf

In [2]:
```

I'm really stumped.

```
> python --version
> Python 3.5.1

> which pip
/Users/skyler/work/TemplateProcessor/.venv/bin/pip
> pip --version
pip 8.1.2 from /Users/skyler/work/TemplateProcessor/.venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)
```

Comment: you start ipython from active venv?

Comment: I was not. However, after installing ipython locally, in the venv via pip, the same error occurs.

Comment: read this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20327621/calling-ipython-from-a-virtualenv), hope this will help.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and found a workaround suggested in [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1415):

> 1.Adding a new file tensorflow/google/init.py:
>
> ```
> try:
>     import pkg_resources
>     pkg_resources.declare_namespace(__name__)
> except ImportError:
>     import pkgutil
>     __path__ = pkgutil.extend_path(__path__, __name__)
>
>     Add namespace_packages to tensorflow/google/protobuf/python/setup.py:
>
> setup(
>     name='protobuf',
>     namespace_packages=['google'],
>     ...
> )
> ```
>
> 2. Recompile / pip install. Good luck!