# Disable ipython autoload virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, conda

I have two different python virtual environment systems, one is `anaconda` and the other is `virtualenv`. (I need to keep both to suit different develop environment).

I installed separate ipython for each virtual env. The problem is that ipython seems to be virtual environment aware, it will automatically load libs from `$VIRTUAL_ENV`.

For example, here are my two different virtual environments

1. `venv`, created by `virtualenv`: `virtualenv /home/<user>/venv`.
   And I set `$VIRTUAL_ENV` by adding `export VIRTUAL_ENV='/home/shao/venv'` in `.bashrc`. Also I installed some required package in this environment by `pip`
2. `p2`, created by `anaconda`: `conda create -n p2 python=2`.

The `$PATH` after activating `p2` is:

```
(p2) shao@T420s:~$ echo $PATH
/home/shao/anaconda3/envs/p2/bin:/home/shao/anaconda3/bin:/home...
```

I am definitely sure that `ipython` binaray is at `/home/shao/anaconda3/envs/p2/bin`.

However, the ipython `sys.path` for p2 is:

```
(p2) shao@T420s:~$ ipython
/home/shao/anaconda3/envs/p2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:724: UserWarning: Attempting to work in a virtualenv. If you encounter problems, please install IPython inside the virtualenv.
  warn("Attempting to work in a virtualenv. If you encounter problems, please "
Python 2.7.12 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:42:40) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

...

In [1]: import sys
In [2]: sys.path
Out[2]: 
['/home/shao/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.18.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/home/shao/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tika-1.13.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/shao/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/superlance-0.11-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/shao/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytz-2016.6.1-py2.7.egg',
 ...
 '/home/shao/venv,
 '/home/shao/anaconda3/envs/p2/bin',
 '/home/shao/anaconda3/envs/p2/lib/python27.zip',
 ...
 '/home/shao/.ipython']
```

As you can see, ipython interpreter gives me warnings and the `sys.path` contains libs from `venv`, which are prior libs from `p2`.

After some google searches, I noticed that recent ipython version is virtual environment [aware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20327621/calling-ipython-from-a-virtualenv), so that it will automatically load these libs from `venv`.

I noticed two things:

1. python interpreter of `p2` will not be affected by `venv`
2. If I RESET `$VIRTUAL_ENV`, ipython interpreter of `p2` will not be affected by `venv`.

Now the question is that is there any graceful way (keep `$VIRTUAL_ENV`)  to disable ipython's initialization behavior, so that `$VIRTUAL_ENV` libs will not be loaded?

Thanks.