# ImportError: cannot import name add_newdocs

Tags: python, windows, numpy, installation

I use Windows8.1 and python 2.7 and I installed the `numpy1.8`. However, whenever I wanna `import numpy` it shows the following error :`ImportError: cannot import name add_newdocs`.

```
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 153, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
ImportError: cannot import name add_newdocs
```

I have checked with `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy` the `add_newdocs` does exist.

Can somebody tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 5):

just reinstall if your use anaconda
`conda install numpy`
I resolve it by doing that

Comment: Worked for me. I just updated the numpy package using conda update numpy command

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem to this.  First make sure that you can at least import numpy in the terminal python  shell without the import error.  If this is not the case, then it could be that a complete reinstall of numpy is necessary (or maybe as some other posts have said your pyc file for add_newdocs went "stale", needs to be deleted and will automatically be recreated and thus problem will be solved)

Or.  The import does work in terminal and, (in my one experience with this bug) it was a problem of file names in the same folder.  Moving the file that imported numpy out of that folder solved the issue.

Or its none of the above and in that case I'm out of ideas

Comment: I had the abovementioned error in a jupyter notebook. Running the import in the console worked, so I did a reinstall of jupyter and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

- in where you save the python ...\Lib\site-packages
- delete this folder "numpy" in the folder "site-packages"
- then in the command line, under the path where you save the python.exe

  in my case: input "cd /d D:\anaconda" in the command line, press Enter

  and then input  "pip install -U numpy" again, press Enter
- after searching for 3 hours, finally find this way works for me, sincerely wish this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error; in my case maybe because there were two python directories in the path (there's normal python and an anaconda python) - both have numpy. The former was added via

```
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages')
```

Replacing this with:

```
site.addsitedir('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages')
```

solved the problem for some reason.

I can't reproduce the original "add_newdocs" error now, though. As written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095037/why-use-sys-path-appendpath-instead-of-sys-path-insert1-path) there are issues with ...insert(0,..), but ..insert(1,..) also gives errors...

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after upgrading Ubuntu. I solved it by updating `numpy`:

```
sudo pip install numpy --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

### ImportError: cannot import name add_newdocs

This error can occur when one of the following files is missing:

[image: Missing files]

This error normally comes when the add_newdocs went stale. 
Don't worry. All you need to do is:

- Go to: **D:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages**
- Delete folder: **numpy**
- Then go to cmd: reinstall numpy by " **pip install numpy** "

And you are good to go

Answer (score -1):

I am using Windows7 64-bit and was facing the same problem before. I solved it by updating `numpy` for Windows:

`pip install numpy --upgrade`

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not really sure about how this works but what is the difference between your answer and Fide's answer?