# Effect of using sys.path.insert(0, path) and sys.path.append(path) when loading modules

Tags: python, pythonpath

I was recently having a problem with a python ImportError, where the module was found when running on my local computer but not found on the CI server. I solved this problem by swapping `sys.path.append(path)` in my script with `sys.path.insert(0, path)` where `path` is the string module location.

Since this is my module and not an installed package ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095037/why-use-sys-path-appendpath-instead-of-sys-path-insert1-path)), why does the order of paths fix this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why use sys.path.append(path) instead of sys.path.insert(1, path)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095037/why-use-sys-path-appendpath-instead-of-sys-path-insert1-path)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Because Python checks in the directories in sequential order, starting at the first directory in the `sys.path` list, until it finds the `.py` file it was looking for.

Normally, the current directory or the directory of the script is the first element in the list, unless you modify it (like you did). From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path):

> As initialized upon program startup, the first item of this list, path[0], is the directory containing the script that was used to invoke the Python interpreter. If the script directory is not available (e.g. if the interpreter is invoked interactively or if the script is read from standard input), path[0] is the empty string, which directs Python to search modules in the current directory first. Notice that the script directory is inserted before the entries inserted as a result of PYTHONPATH.

So, most probably, you had a `.py` file with the same name as the module you were trying to import from, in the current directory (where the script was being run from).

Also, something to note about `ImportError`s - Let's say the import error says:
`ImportError: No module named main`. This doesn't mean `main.py` is overwritten - if it was overwritten it would still exist and we would not have issues trying to read it. It's some module above this that got overwritten with a `.py` or some other file.

For example, consider a directory structure that looks like this:

```
 - test
    - shared
       - __init__.py
       - phtest.py
    - testmain.py
```

Now from `testmain.py`, I call `from shared import phtest`, which works fine.

Now let's say I introduce a `shared.py` in `test` directory:

```
 - test
    - shared
       - __init__.py
       - phtest.py
    - testmain.py 
    - shared.py
```

Now when I try to do `from shared import phtest` from `testmain.py`, I get the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'phtest'
```

As you can see above, the file that introduced the issue is `shared.py`, not `phtest.py`.

Comment: My module was something.main, I tried changing it to something.engine to see if this was the problem, however I still had the ImportError, this makes me think it was wasn't a module name/file clash.

Comment: The last line of the traceback was "ImportError: No module named main"

Comment: Do you have a traceback, maybe that can help

Comment: Here is the circleci output, it's a little limited I'm afraid - https://circleci.com/gh/bioboxes/command-line-interface/18

Comment: I got a similar error when I renamed 'main' to 'engine'.

Comment: The issue is most probably caused by some `biobox_cli.py` in the current directory (or a directory in PYTHONPATH variable) , check both places.

Comment: @MichaelBarton From the error it looks like , it is complaining about a directory named 'biobox_cli' in the path

Comment: I had problems when I named a file and folder the same

Answer (score 91):

I'm quite a beginner in Python and I found the answer of Anand was very good but quite complicated to me, so I try to reformulate :

1) `insert` and `append` methods are not specific to `sys.path` and as in other languages they add an item into a list or array and :
  * `append(item)` add `item` to the end of the list,
  * `insert(n, item)` inserts the `item` at the nth position in the list (`0` at the beginning, `1` after the first element, etc ...).

2) As Anand said, python search the import files in each directory of the path in the order of the path, so :
  * If you have no file name collisions, the order of the path has no impact,
  * If you look after a function already defined in the path and you use `append` to add your path, you will not get your function but the predefined one.

But I think that it is better to use `append` and not `insert` to not overload the standard behaviour of Python, and use non-ambiguous names for your files and methods.