# ImportError: No Module Named, when module exists

Tags: python

I have the following relevant libraries and files in my project:

```
Project_Library
    data
        some_folder
            sub_folder1
                script1.py
            sub_folder2
                script2.py

    scripts
        __init__.py
        lib_a.py
```

The code in `script1.py` works perfectly and looks a bit like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "C:/Project_Library/scripts") #


from lib_a import *
#Some more irrelevant code here
```

The code in `script2.py` doesn't work, Python claims `ImportError: No Module named lib_a` while I actually copied and pasted the heading of `script1.py`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "C:/Project_Library/scripts") #

print sys.path #looks good

from lib_a import * #Crashes here
#again, more code
```

What possible reason can cause this?

**EDIT**:

A very interesting note. If I try to run `script2.py` after copying the file into `sub_folder1` without changing a thing, it DOES work. Then why doesn't it work in `sub_folder2`?

**EDIT2**:

I did get it to work, for some reason just creating a new file and copying and pasting the file's content into it just worked miraculously! I still kept the original file with the original file name, as it still DOESN'T work on it, very interesting. I wonder what the source of the problem could possibly be

Comment: Where is lib_a ? Check your PYTHONPATH variable

Comment: You can try to look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31291608/effect-of-using-sys-path-insert0-path-and-sys-pathappend-when-loading-modul) post (Anand S Kumar's answe):

Comment: What is the content of your `__init__.py` ?

Comment: @3kt just `__all__ = ['lib_a']`. But does it even matter? I don't import scripts as a package, I add it as a folder to my path variable.

Comment: How are you executing these files?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Simply `python file_name.py` from the command line (with the working directory the same as the file's location)

Comment: That rules out metadata of the file being responsible for how it is executed... and if you do something like `with open("script1.py") as sc1, open("script2.py") as sc2: print(sc1.read() == sc2.read())` it shows `True` but you get different results when executing them?  I'm wondering if there is a hidden character in the path that didn't copy over or something...

Comment: I guess it is only a formatting problem, but your directory structure shows the library in `"C:/Project_Library/scripts"`.

Comment: @mkiever Yeah, it was by mistake.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen yes, it outputs `True`. This is really odd, I have to say