# Unable to import files in python

Tags: python

I have written Python code which is divided among couple of files i.e.

```
record_1.py
record_2.py
record_3.py
record_4.py
main.py
```

All these files are placed in a common folder:

```
/user/mario/python/sampletest
```

When I am trying to import the above files in main.py it's giving error While executing the below command:

```
$] python  main.py
ImportError: No module named record_1
```

Below is the main.py code:

```
import jaydebeapi
import record_1,record_2,record_3,record_4


def main():
def teradata_conn():
    try:
        conn_teradata = jaydebeapi.connect(jclassname='com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver',
                                           url="jdbc:teradata://10.10.10.10",
                                           driver_args=['@user','@pass'],
                                           jars=['/user/mario/python/jar/tdgssconfig.jar','/user/mario/python/jar/terajdbc4.jar'])
        print("Connection was successful")            
        record_1()
        record_2()
        record_3()
        record_4()

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated.

```
import sys
print (repr(sys.path))


['', '/user/mario/anaconda2/lib/python27.zip', 
'/user/mario/anaconda2/lib/python2.7', 
'/user/mario/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
'/user/mario/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', 
'/user/mario/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', 
'/user/mario/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 
'/user/mario/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-old', 
'/user/mario/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', 
'/user/mario/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages', 
'/user/mario/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/aeosa', 
'/user/mario/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site
packages/IPython/extensions', 
'/user/mario/.ipython']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(info from https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path):

For `import` to work, the directory where the modules are must be in the path (sys.path). The path will **normally** include the directory where the script you're running is located, but this may be broken if Python is unable to determine where that is (e.g., if you do something like `python <script.py` ). In such cases, Python should add the empty string to the path, meaning 'current directory'.

From the output of `print (repr(sys.path))`, it appears that the script was ran in a way that prevented Python from knowing where it is located - Python inserted the empty string "" as the first item in the path, this happens when you do something like this:

```
python  </usr/mario/python/sampletest/main.py
```

Your system modules paths (.../anaconda2/lib/...) suggests an installation of Python that I am not familiar with. If you actually ran the command exactly as you quoted it (`python main.py` - when the current directory is where both main and the modules are), it should have worked - but in your installation, the `python` command might be some wrapper script that changes directories or does other things before running the interpreter that mess it up.

Even though it didn't have `"/usr/mario/python/sampletest"` in the path, having "" in the path makes Python look for modules in the current directory. Given that in your case you got a failure, it means that (at the time the script started), the current directory was NOT `/usr/mario/python/sampletest`. See what `import os ; print (os.getcwd())` will give you, if it isn't your modules directory, that would explain it.

Likely solutions to fix the problem, choose depending on your needs:

- give the full path to your script to python, e.g. `python /usr/mario/python/sampletest/main.py`.
- try ensuring that the current directory is `/usr/mario/python/sampletest` when you run the script. Using `import os ; os.chdir("something")` before the other imports is an option, too.
- set the PYTHONPATH variable to that directory (e.g., if your shell is sh or bash: `PYTHONPATH=/usr/mario/python/sampletest python main.py`
- modify sys.path[] to include your directory, e.g., sys.path.insert(0,"your-modules-path"), as suggested in another answer here.

Comment: Thank you Leo. I have shared the output with the main question.

Comment: I tried the way you suggested but still not getting the output. Have shared the results in the original question.

Comment: From your latest update, it seems you got the import paths right. Are you getting ImportError or something else? I see a different problem in your code: you have record_1(), and record_1 - if it got imported successfully - is not actually callable (it is a module object, you cannot call that).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Leo K. There were certain things which I did in my code along with the suggestions posted here. Now its working.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not an expert in Python. I vaguely remember running into this issue and when I added the following, it worked. But again, I was trying to import modules that are in different directory.

```
sys.path.insert(0,'/user/mario/python/sampletest')
```

Comment: What's the significance of (0,' ') ?

Comment: Here's the link to a post which explained the significance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31291608/effect-of-using-sys-path-insert0-path-and-sys-pathappend-when-loading-modul

Comment: vaguely remembering things not relevant to the question is not a good basis to answer on SO.