# How can I import variables from parent directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I just want to import python file with hyper parameters in the parent directory, but I just got the system error.

Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import

The directory structure is as below.

```
Project directory
+-- package
|   +-- dataset
|   |   +-- __init__.py
|   |   +-- dataset.py
|   +-- models
|       +-- __init__.py
|       +-- cnn.py
+-- __init__.py
+-- hparams.py
+-- main.py
```

What I want to do is import variables of hparams.py in dataset.py

I've tried several lines as below, but none of these works.

```
from ..hparams import * 

from ...hparams import *

from .. import hparams

from ... import hparams
```

What should I do for import?

Comment: Which script you are trying to run?

Comment: `from Project.hparams import *`

Comment: No which script do you run? `cnn.py` I guess?

Comment: I am trying to run main.py. cnn.py is for model architecture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell python where to look for this file, you can't do it by default like you're trying to do. Besides, as your directory architecture suggests, you need to look in the parent directory *of* the parent directory of your file `dataset.py` in order to access `hparams.py`. 
So what you can do is just add these 2 lines of code at the beginning of `dataset.py`

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '..\..')
```

Then you can perform `from hparams import *` or `import hparams` as usual.
More info about `sys.path.insert` [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31291608/effect-of-using-sys-path-insert0-path-and-sys-pathappend-when-loading-modul)