# Where does python look if your sys.path uses relative directory?

Tags: python, sys

I have a project like:

```
project/
    foo/
       other.py
    bar/
       baz.py
```

If I code something like:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../foo')

from foo import other
```

It doesn't work.  But if I move foo into the bar directory it works.  I realize this is bad code style, but how is this relative path searched and where does the documentation define it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`from foo import other` will append `foo` to each of the directories in `sys.path`. So it's looking for `../foo/foo/other.py`, but the actual path is just `../foo/other.py`.

You should just insert `..` into `sys.path`, then it will look for `../foo/other.py`. Or if you only want to include that directory in the path, just use `import other`, without `from foo`.

Comment: then why does it work when foo is in the bar directory?  Shouldn't it be doubling up the search for foo/foo/bar?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are in the `baz` directory, you need to include your parent directory `..` in the path. Then when you do `from foo`, the foo directory in your parent directory is found.

This works:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '..')

from foo import other
```

Read more:

- [Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31291669/1858466)
- [The Definitive Guide to Python import Statements](https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html)

---

Alternatively, since you included `../foo` in the path, you could simply do `import other`, like so:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '..\foo')

import other
```