# unable to import python files present in another directory in python project

Tags: python, python-import

I have a Python project with nested modules:

```
root_dir:
   |-code_base
     |-task_code.py
     |-__init__.py
   |-utils_dir
     |-mysql_util.py
     |-__init__.py
   |-__init__.py
```

I'm using Visual Studio IDE and, loading the root_dir folder.

When i'm trying to **import mysql_util file in tasks_code file**, im getting Import Error.
Import statement i'm using : `from utils_dir.mysql_util import MySQLUtils`

Error i'm receiving:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils_dir'`

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31291608/effect-of-using-sys-path-insert0-path-and-sys-pathappend-when-loading-modul

Comment: You should put you work ditrctory in your pythonpath

Answer (score 0):

Before you import put in these two lines:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../")
```

and then the import should work

Answer (score 0):

Try relative explicit import:

```
from ..utils_dir.mysql_util import MySQLUtils
```

Comment: Getting the following error.  ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: You'll need to add `root_dir` as a library/package. You can either do it by adding it to your PYTHONPATH env in your shell or use `sys.path` and append the full path of `root_dir`