# PYCHARM import caffe error

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, caffe, pycaffe

I have tried several ideas to make caffe work on pycharm.

I have also added the path to the pycharm as well.
[image]

[image]

import caffe doesnt work in pycharm but works in the terminal.

the caffe folder is also in my pythonpath.

[image]

Comment: Consider [changing your](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095037/why-use-sys-path-appendpath-instead-of-sys-path-insert1-path) insert to `sys.path` to `sys.path.insert(1, caffee_root + 'python')` . This ***might*** be a reason for this.

Comment: @DimitrisJim why do you think so?

Comment: your import error complains about CUDA lib. is it possible that CUDA is not  in pycharm's path?

Comment: @Shai Mainly due to the abnormalities it sometimes introduces. I guessed since the only difference between executing via pycharm and via terminal is the added `sys.path.insert` operation, it might have something to do with it.

Comment: Tried the sys.path.insert(1, caffee_root + 'python') as well gives the same error.

Comment: also tried adding the cuda lib dir to pycharms sys path.Throws the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed the issue.
I just had to edit the `/etc/ld.so.conf` file and add the lib dir of the Cuda libraries. In my case I added:

```
/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64
```

Then run `sudo ldconfig` in the terminal and restart Pycharm. It should work.

Comment: How did you fix this?  mine is coming up with Caffe has no attribute but works fine in terminal