# ImportError: No module named 'gammu'

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I work on Ubuntu Xenial (16.04) with `python3`, I also installed anaconda.

I installed `python3-gammu` (with apt install python3-gammu or/and pip install python3-gammu) to test send SMS.

Just run python3 console and

```
>>> import gammu
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'gammu'


import sys
print(sys.path)
```

only return anaconda paths !

If I run

```
sudo find -iname gammu
…
./usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gam
…
```

so if I add this path:

```
>>> sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/')
>>> import gammu
```

and it works !

Could you clarify this library path issue?

Comment: You've already basically identified the problem: your module is installed somewhere that is not in Python's import path.

Comment: it's a separate environment issue, when I run python3, it is anaconda environment: `Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)`, so probably I should install python3-gammu with conda … but If I launch `conda install python3-gammu`, it returns `PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels`

Comment: Obviously `python3-gammu` is installed to your python dist but not in your `anaconda` env. This may be due to the use of `apt get` or `pip`. Please, check whether `pip` belongs to `anaconda` or by typing `which pip` to the terminal.

Comment: @MaxPowers : it was probably with `apt` because `which pip` returns `…/anaconda3/bin/pip` and `pip install python3-gammu` doesn't find python3-gammu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/
```

To keep it at next reboot, put this line in your ~/.bashrc :

```
# added by Anaconda3 4.2.0 installer
export PATH="/home/my_user_name/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
export PYTHONPATH="/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/:$PYTHONPATH"
```

to active new .bashrc, do not forget to run

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to import any package it will check sys.path, which contains all paths of packages. If it find the package you want to import it will import it.

sorry for bad english...

[Why use sys.path.append(path) instead of sys.path.insert(1, path)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095037/why-use-sys-path-appendpath-instead-of-sys-path-insert1-path)

You may get clarity after seeing this ?

Comment: Thanks, `virtualenv` (or `venv`) could probably solve my issue, but in my case I think the problem are linux python3 and anaconda3 is already in separate environments… and differents paths