# Importing from a file in previous path in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I have this file structure:

```
.
   test/db_test.py
   models/user.py
```

I want to import `user.py` in `db_test.py`, for example i try it:

```
from ..models.user import User
```

but have this error:

```
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

How can do this work?

1. all path have `__init__.py` file
2. i don't want to use appending in sys.path

thank for your answers

Comment: You are missing a `__init__.py` in the root directory.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid , my root directory have `__init__.py`

Comment: possible duplicate of [nightmare with relative imports, how does pep 366 work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943847/nightmare-with-relative-imports-how-does-pep-366-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running the script as a package? Try running the following from the directory containing your package root directory:

```
python -m your_package_name.test.db_test
```

My test that this worked for was:

```
your_package_name/
    __init__.py
    test/
        __init__.py
        db_test.py
    models/
        __init__.py
        user.py
```

Where "db_test.py" contained:

```
from ..models.user import User
```

So I ran that command from the parent directory of "your_package_name".

Comment: I should note that I don't normally work with python 3 so no guarantees.

Comment: it's worked, but i don't want run an script like an module and `from ..models.user import User` don't work!

Comment: Unless this changed in python 3, you can't use relative imports from a non-package context. A relative import means you are importing relative to your current package/subpackage. If you want to run it as a script I think you'll have to have the necessary modules in your sys.path.