# Import in Python 3

Tags: python

**structure:**

```
app
app/__init__.py
app/mymodule.py
app/myscript.py
```

**mymodule.py:**

```
class One: pass
```

**myscript.py:**

```
from .mymodule import One
```

And I see an error:

```
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

Why? I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/python-3-relative-imports) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943847/nightmare-with-relative-imports-how-does-pep-366-work), but I cant understand, how to fix it. Please, explain me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`from .mymodule import One` needs to be `from mymodule import One` ( remove the dot)

Comment: I had the same problem to get it working with PyCharm. The solution I found is I changed the content root (`Preferences > Project : [projectname] > Project Structure`) and defined all paths with complete dotted path w.r.t project root, i.e. from `top_level_module.X.Y import something`. My content root was the directory one level above top_level_module